# Stop duplicate database entries on MVC php

Tags: php, mysql

As the title suggests , im using a MVC system to display tables in a database . This also allows users to add new entries into tables.

I need a way of stopping duplicate entries from being added and a message telling the user that their is already an entry that matches the details they have entered.

The code for this is stored in the controller_create.php file . I have posted the whole file bellow along with the a create statement from the sql file. The code to stop duplication only needs to work for one of the tables.

This code is what I have so far :

```
      if ($class_obj == "supplier")
  {
    $referred_as = $_POST['referred_as'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count `supplier` WHERE `referred_as` = ' " . $referred_as. " ' ");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        echo "Supplier already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO supplier (referred_as) VALUES ('".$_POST[referred_as]."')";
    }
  }
```

I think im on the right line . Any help is welcome.

Create statement for the supplier table :

```
--
-- Table structure for table `supplier`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supplier` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `goodsandservices` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `based` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `referred_as` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `supplier`
--

INSERT INTO `supplier` (`id`, `goodsandservices`, `based`, `referred_as`) VALUES
```

Controller_create.php :

```
    <?
$class_obj=$_REQUEST['class_obj'];

$pino = array(); // this is a local array used to store retrieved attributes of selected objects

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key_REQUEST => $value_REQUEST)
{
if (substr($key_REQUEST,0,6) == 'input_')
{
if ($key_REQUEST != "input_id")
{
$pino = $pino + array(substr($key_REQUEST,6) => $value_REQUEST);
}
}
}
//echo "<P>.".print_r($pino);
  $this_obj = MyActiveRecord::Create($class_obj, $pino );

  $this_obj->save(); // crucial command: disactivate  only if you don't want to save...

  $last_inserted_record = $this_obj->id;

  $relation_name = $_REQUEST['jt_name'];
  $relation_class = $_REQUEST['jt_class'];



  if ($class_obj == "supplier")
  {
    $referred_as = $_POST['referred_as'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count `supplier` WHERE `referred_as` = ' " . $referred_as. " ' ");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        echo "Supplier already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO supplier (referred_as) VALUES ('".$_POST[referred_as]."')";
    }
  }


 // echo "<p>relation_name = ".$relation_name." - strpos = ".strpos ($relation_name,$class_obj)."";


  echo "<p>";

  foreach ($_REQUEST as $key_REQUEST => $value_REQUEST)
{
if (substr($key_REQUEST,0,9) == 'jt_input_')
{
//$pino = (substr($key_REQUEST,9) => $value_REQUEST);

$that_id = $value_REQUEST;
//echo " that_id = ".$that_id;
//echo " key = ".$key_REQUEST;


if (strpos($relation_name,$class_obj)>0)
{
$obj2 = $this_obj;
//$obj1 = $that_id;
$obj1 = MyActiveRecord::FindById($relation_class, $that_id);
}
else
{
$obj1 = $this_obj;
$obj2 = MyActiveRecord::FindById($relation_class, $that_id);
//$obj2 = $that_id;
}
//MyActiveRecord::Link($obj1,$obj2);
MyActiveRecord::Link($obj1,$obj2);
//echo "rel_name = ".$relation_name." - class = ".$class_obj." pos = ".strpos($relation_name,$class_obj)." obj1 = ".$obj1->id." - obj2 = ".$obj2->id."; ";

}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to note. First and foremost, if this is a legitimate hard constraint that you don't want this to be duplicated, enforce it at the database level with a UNIQUE constraint.

Secondly, you shouldn't be using mysql_query. Use mysqli. You're also not escaping your inputs which is a gigantic security risk. Use prepared statements with PDO. Seriously, learn this now. It is unacceptable to not do it.

You can use num_rows from the mysqli_result object to determine the number of rows that were affected. If it's 0, and there weren't any errors, then you can safely assume that it already existed and output your error message appropriately.

Lastly, you're missing a "FROM" in your SELECT.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay , so ill enforce it at a database level . Secondly , i realise there is a security risk , but this is simply a project that is not intended for actual use and is run localy. Could you give some example code for the num_rows ? Finaly , i didnt notice the missing FROM , so thanks for that.

Comment: I understand, but it's just a REALLY bad habit to get into. Always escape your inputs. Assuming you're using mysqli, $result = $mysqli->query("insert here"); then use $result->num_rows.

Comment: Thanks , ill look into escaping the inputs . As far as im aware , im using mysql and not mysqli